# Can't assign querySelectorAll() to a variable - weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I was trying to crawl a very old website for a specific tag, I need to get it by it's for= attribute. So I used this piece of code.

```
var character = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_1]");
```

For some reason it returns an `undefined`, but I was using this script for a few days now and it worked like a charm. Here's the fun part. Typing that command in browsers console will result in `undefined`.  But typing this alone:

```
document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_1]");
```

Will return a proper `NodeList`. Why it won't assign to a variable...?

edit: It seems that deleting `var` and typing `character` without it will make it work. It's resolved but I would still love to get an answer to "why is this happening"?

edit2:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var character = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_" + i +"]");
    console.log(character); // this will return [] from the script.
    var color = character[0].children[0].style.color;
}
```

A simple for loop. All I get is `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`. But I can type in the very same command `document.querySelectorAll...` and it will work in the browser and will return `NodeList`.

I had it working like this in a very hacky script. It worked.

```
var character1 = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_1]");
var characterColor1 = character1[0].children[0].style.color;
```

edit3:

```
var character1 = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_1]");
var characterColor1 = character1[0].children[0].style.color;

var character2 = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_2]");
var characterColor2 = character2[0].children[0].style.color;
// ...
```

The above code works without a single problem though. I don't think it's DOM not being ready as this code is also run from Greasemonkey script and it works. The only difference is the for loop.

Comment: Are you sure `character` is undefined? or is the console just *saying* undefined. If you put `var x = 10` it will say undefined, but if you type `x` right after that, you'll get `10`.

Comment: This is “normal” console behavior. Variable assignments show `undefined`. `var character = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_1]"); character;` will work as expected.

Comment: I am pretty sure. Because I use that scipt as Greasemonkey extension. And it throws errors because it is `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the _full_ code with all the relevant details relating to variable scope?

Comment: @Xufox added a bit of context.

Comment: _“All I get is ‘Cannot read property `children` of `undefined`.’”_ — but that doesn’t mean `character` is undefined; `character[0]` is undefined! It really sounds like the DOM just isn’t loaded at that time.

Comment: Not really. If I toss away the for loop it works properly (see edit 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buhah, as I said in edit 3 "the only difference is the for loop". I was so busy trying to find an answer in the DOM-related things that I made the simplest mistake ever done in programming.

See?

```
char_1
```

With...

```
for(var i = 0...)
```

0! And I was testing char_1 in the browser instead of char_0. Which - truly - returns `[]` instead of something useful. Time to go on a holiday break I guess, my brain seems to be there already. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = ""; // returns undefined, because it's a var assignment.
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

That's expected behavior when pasted into the console.

> edit: It seems that deleting var and typing character without it will make it work. It's resolved

I'm afraid you're creating a global scope variable now. or perhaps characters is an already defined variable in that scope.

Comment: `var character = document.querySelectorAll("label[for=char_1");
console.log(character);
var color = character[0].children[0].style.color;`

That piece of code is failing because children cannot be used on `undefined`. But when I go to the browsers console and type that in myself it will return the proper NodeList (like you have shown above).

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @galkowskit — Which of the two `children` is undefined?